# Need updated Windows 7 driver for Digitech USB Oscilloscope model QC-1931

Tags: windows-7

My Digitech USB scope (model QC-1931) used to work OK under WindowsXP.
Problem arose with installing S/W on Windows 7 O/S, Driver will not install

Anyone out there with an updated driver or work-around?

Thanks

Regards;
BenL

Comment: 32 bit or 64 bit ???

Answer (score 1):

go to website http://www.mainelectronics.com/scope-ct.htm and download software for DSO 3100 usb oscilloscope and use this run the digitech Qc1931. This software has 64bit drivers and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think digitech stopped their support for your model , I am not able to find your product in their homesite http://www.digitech.com/software_support/

Answer (score 0):

It doesn’t matter. Manually select the driver from the install disc and it will work. Also, run the installer in compatibility-mode if it doesn’t work normally.